# MongoDb: Query not pulling item from array - why?

Tags: mongodb

The intention of the query below is to pull items from the locs array, where x=2 and y=9.  However items with these values remain in the array after this query.

```
 db.myCollection.update(
       { }, //All records
       { $pull: { 'locs' : { $elemMatch : {'x' : 2 , 'y' : 9 } } } }
 )
```

Could anyone tell me why it's not working?

Edit: Example document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55555555555"),
  "locs" : [{
      "x" : 2,
      "y" : 9
    }],
  "v" : 99
}
```

Comment: Can you please add an example document as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, `$pull` does not work like this. It removes "a value from an array" (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/). You can not use `$elemMatch` here, but neither do you have to.

So if you have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    'title': 'example',
    'locs': [
        { x: 2, y: 12 },
        { x: 7, y: 9 },
        { x: 2, y: 9 },
    ]
}
```

The follow should remove your x:2 / y:9 value pair:

```
db.so.update(
    {},
    { $pull: { 'locs' : { 'x' : 2 , 'y' : 9 } } }
);
```

Which then has:

```
{
    'title': 'example',
    'locs': [
        { x: 2, y: 12 },
        { x: 7, y: 9 },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification Derick. I think I need to read up on a few points including the purpose of elemMatch.

Comment: I think you understand ``$elemMatch`` just fine, it's just that $pull just wants values, and not expressions/queries.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need not use `$elemMatch`. Try with the following, it should work:

```
db.myCollection.update({}, {$pull: {'locs' : {'x' : 2 , 'y' : 9}}})
```

EDIT: or @Derick's answer, which is rather better than mine.